# Main character is reincarnated, loses her sight and escapes a lab?

Tags: story-identification, novel, reincarnation

Does anyone know the name of a novel with a child female main character?  She reincarnated, is kidnapped, and is experimented on since birth. She loses her sight, and escapes the scientist with someone else from the lab.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Once you've created your account, please do take the [tour] and visit the [help]. They should cover basics like voting and accepting correct answer, and how to [edit] more details in and how to reply to comments. Take a look over our [tag:story-identification] usage to see what sort of extra details would help us answer.

Comment: Could it be the Netflix serie The OA? Here's the wikipedia synopsis: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_OA#Synopsis

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty sure this is the book [Inventors System](https://www.webnovel.com/book/inventors-system_18925033806748105). The synopsis says:

> Crazy inventor transmigrates into a different world and is born as a baby.
> her first day into a new life she gets kidnapped by a crazy scientist.

and this is a close match to your description.

Comment: Could you provide some information about how this work matches the description?